# How to Create Self Terminating XML File using libxml2

Tags: libxml2

I'm trying to create self terminating XML File using libxml2 , but as far as i have searched i got xmlSaveNoEmptyTags only, but i'm not sure how to use it. I'm using Objective C and libxml2 in Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to analyze basic [libxml examples](http://xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html). Does this one help: [`io2.c`](http://xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html#io2.c) ? If not, edit the question and show the exact xml contents you would like to obtain.